# How to link file to homepage?

Tags: jsp, hyperlink

I made a homepage using JSP. This page show server computer's file. I want to make this file can be downloaded via  link. What can I do for this feature? Is there any way to link file to homepage? I'm using apache tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to call the `Servlet` on clicking on `hyperlink`. This post will describe how to call the `Servlet` if your not using `javascript`.

[calling the servlet on click of hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907482/call-a-servlet-on-click-of-hyperlink).

In the `Servlet` you have to write code for the downloding file. I think this post will help you.

[how to download / upload files from / to server](http://www.journaldev.com/1964/servlet-upload-file-download-example)