# jsp page doesn't appears?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

my work consists on viewing a JSP page using servlets the problem is that Produit.jsp has worked normally while it didn't work for the SaisieProduit.jsp (so it wasn't a problem of web.xml), also when I run SaisieProduit.jsp without passing by the servlet class it worked normally.

here is my servlet class

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path=req.getServletPath();

        if(path.equals("/index.do")){
            req.getRequestDispatcher("produits.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }
        else if(path.equals("/chercher.do")){
            String motCle=req.getParameter("motCle");

            ProduitModel model=new ProduitModel();
            model.setMotCle(motCle);            
            List<Produit> produits=new ArrayList<Produit>();
             produits=metier.produitsParMC(motCle);
            model.setProduits(produits);
            req.setAttribute("model", model);
            req.getRequestDispatcher("produits.jsp").forward(req, resp);

        }

        else if(path.equals("/saisie.do")){
            req.getRequestDispatcher("SaisieProduit.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }



    }

}
```

here is the link of saisie.do

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="index.do">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="saisie.do">Saisie</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

[image]

when I click on saisie a blanket page appears

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing but `String path=req.getServletPath();` would print only the URL you set in your servlet, so the conditions you are trying to work with wont trigger. Print your path-Variable and you can check that.

Here is a way to do what I understood you are trying to do: [call servlet on link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907482/call-a-servlet-on-click-of-hyperlink)